# MVVM Behavior in another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I created a assembly for my MVVM Project in WPF. In my assembly i have a Behavior for activate when I want to sort a column in a datagrid.

Behavior SortColumn

```
 public class SortColumn : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public string Property = "";
    public bool MeaningSort = true;


    public static DependencyProperty AtSortingColumnCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "AtSortingColumnCommand", typeof(ICommand),
           typeof(SortColumn));
    public static ICommand GetAtSortingColumnCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(AtSortingColumnCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAtSortingColumnCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AtSortingColumnCommandProperty, value);
    }
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Sorting += AssociatedObject_Sorting;
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Sorting -= AssociatedObject_Sorting;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    //Selon MeaningSort, on renvoie une chaine OrderBy en ASC ou DESC
    //Ex: MonChamp ASC
    private void AssociatedObject_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        string FiledName = e.Column.SortMemberPath;

        if (Property == null || (Property != FiledName && MeaningSort != false))
        {
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending; 
            MeaningSort = false;

            var atEnd = GetAtSortingColumnCommand(element);
            if (atEnd != null)
            {
                atEnd.Execute(FiledName + " ASC");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            MeaningSort = true;

            var atEnd = GetAtSortingColumnCommand(element);
            if (atEnd != null)
            {
                atEnd.Execute(FiledName + " DESC");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And in my XAML

```
 <D:DataGridTemplate  x:Name="Datagrid" 
                         TablePaged:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding LoadCommand}"  
                         TablePaged:SortColumn.AtSortingColumnCommand="{Binding SortingColumnCommand}" 
                         Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataProduits,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

So it works fine ONLY when my file is in the same assembly. Maybe i'm not on the same Instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attaching a behavior is quite intuitive, and should be done in the following manner:

1) Include the following xmlns in the document header

```
 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

2) Define the xmlns in which the behavior resides (Also in the document header)

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.MyBehaviors;assembly=MyAssembly"
```

3) Attach the behavior to the element in the following manner:

```
 <Element>
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <b:MyBehavior MyDependencyProperty={Binding Foo}>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </Element>
```

As long that you follow these steps, the behavior will become attached, but mind this:

In order for the behavior to attach, the element to which the behavior is attached must be a subclass of the type specified by the behavior's generic parameter (if you are using the generic *Behavior* base class).

Alternatively, it must be a subclass of *DependencyObject* if you are using the non generic *Behavior* base class.

EDIT 1:

The behavior you implemented is for a DataGrid, yet your XAML attached it to the DataGridTemplate class, all this while the Attached Property is registered to your behavior instead of to some TargetType.. it really seems all over the place...

EDIT 2:

It seems that you took the attached behavior approach, which kind of makes subclassing behavior pointless..

If you already took the time to subclass *Behavior*, you might as well make those properties regular Dependency Properties.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much ! Thanks to your advice, I was able to correct the problem. The code following code works perfectly from another Assembly

```
 public class SortColumn
{
    public static string Property = "";
    public static bool MeaningSort = true;


    public static DependencyProperty AtSortingColumnCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AtSortingColumnCommand",
        typeof(ICommand), typeof(SortColumn), new PropertyMetadata(OnAtSortingColumnCommandChanged));

    public static ICommand GetAtSortingColumnCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(AtSortingColumnCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAtSortingColumnCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AtSortingColumnCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnAtSortingColumnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myDataGrid = d as DataGrid;
        if (myDataGrid != null)
        {
            myDataGrid.Sorting -= HandleColumnSorting;
            myDataGrid.Sorting += HandleColumnSorting;
        }
    }

    static void HandleColumnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        var myDataGridSorting = sender as DataGrid;
        string FiledName = e.Column.SortMemberPath;

        if (Property == null || (Property != FiledName && MeaningSort != false))
        {
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            MeaningSort = false;

            var atEnd = GetAtSortingColumnCommand(myDataGridSorting);
            if (atEnd != null)
            {
                atEnd.Execute(FiledName + " ASC");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            MeaningSort = true;

            var atEnd = GetAtSortingColumnCommand(myDataGridSorting);
            if (atEnd != null)
            {
                atEnd.Execute(FiledName + " DESC");
            }
        }
    }
}
```